# Overlay on full video length when making video from images sequence using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am facing a issue when I overlay watermark image on video (I am making video from images sequence).The issue is that the overlay image only append on first image and ignoring all other images in video. I want to overlay this image on whole video. Possibly I am wrongly applying -filter_graph to input stream. I am executing below mentioned script. I searched online but did not find any relevant answer.

```
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i img%2d.jpeg -i watermark.png -i music.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=x=10:y=10" video.mp4
```

Comment: Do all images in the sequence have the same resolution?

Comment: @Gyan images resolution may be different

Comment: Ok, that's causing the issue. Can be worked around But all frames will resized to the same size as the first frame.

Comment: @Gyan, exactly issue resolved, different resolution images causing the issue. Issue resolved after i resized images to same resolution. Thanks. One more thing if we have to apply same zoompan filter on all images, how can we do image2 sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different resolution images causing the issue. Issue resolved after resizing images to same resolution.